# Azure PIM PowerShell Script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

On Azure Portal we can grant **Contributor** role to Subscription using PIM for limited period of time.
Like 1 - 2 - 3 hours.
Those are called eligible assignments.

Anyone has tried assigning eligible assignments using powershell ?
As per my research  -- AZureADPreview module is present.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles )

But it is still under preview and doens't have full functionality.

Comment: please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles#assign-a-role) it may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the functionality has already been mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles#assign-a-role), give a sample here to elaborate on the specific usage.

For example, you want to assign the `Application Administrator` role to a user, then the script should be:

**Note:** The `-ResourceId` parameter uses your AAD tenant id `<tenant-id>`.

```
$role = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition -ProviderId aadRoles -ResourceId "<tenant-id>" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}

$schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.AzureADMSPrivilegedSchedule
$schedule.Type = "Once"
$schedule.StartDateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
$schedule.endDateTime = "2021-07-25T20:49:11.770Z"
Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId aadRoles -Schedule $schedule -ResourceId "<tenant-id>" -RoleDefinitionId $role.Id -SubjectId "<object-id of user or group>" -AssignmentState "Eligible" -Type "AdminAdd"
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing
Code: UnknownError
Message:
  DateTimeStamp: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 17:19:46 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId 'AzureResources'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.GetAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmen

Comment: Hello guys , always use - Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedResource to start with this script

Comment: @ManvendraBele Did you find how to fix this Forbidden issue? Running into it currently.

Comment: That's not what OP asked. Your answer is specific to AAD role and OP is asking about Contributor on a subscription, i.e this is an Azure resource.